# the trait `rustc_serialize::json::ToJson` is not implemented for the type `Json`

Tags: rust

I'm using Nickel.rs and MongoDB to create a REST API. I've defined an `enum ApiResult<T>` and I've implemented the `nickel::Responder` trait for it. `ApiResult<T>` can be generated from any type that implements the trait `ToApiResult`. I'm trying to implement this trait for `mongodb::error::Result<Option<bson::Document>>` but I get an error:

> the trait `rustc_serialize::json::ToJson` is not implemented for the
>   type `Json`

I checked the documentation and can see that `ToJson` has been implemented for `Json`:

```
impl ToJson for Json {
    fn to_json(&self) -> Json { self.clone() }
}
```

So what is causing the error? Here is an MCVE that reproduces the issue:

```
    // rustc_serialize
extern crate rustc_serialize;
use rustc_serialize::json::{self,Json, ToJson};
use std::{result,error};

enum ApiResult<T : Sized + ToJson>{
    Ok(T),
    Err(T)
}

trait ToApiResult<T: Sized + ToJson>{
    fn to_api_result(&self)->ApiResult<T>;
}

impl<Json> ToApiResult<Json> for Result<Option<String>,String> {

    fn to_api_result(&self)->ApiResult<Json>{

        match *self {
            Ok(Some(text))=>{
                ApiResult::Ok(text.to_json())
            },
            Ok(None)=>{
                ApiResult::Error(().to_json())
            },
            Err(e)=>{
                ApiResult::Error(e.to_json())
            }

        }
    }

}

fn main(){
    let r = Result::Ok(Some("hello"));
    print!("{}",r.to_api_result());
}
```

Comment: Sure, I'll get right on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem occurs here:

```
impl<Json> ToApiResult<Json> for Result<Option<String>, String>
//   ^^^^
```

Specifically, this defines a new generic type parameter called `Json`. This is **not** the `rustc_serialize::json::Json` enum.

Beyond that, you have some other small errors that prevent compilation. Once the main error is cleared up, you would have to address:

1. Typos (`Error` vs `Err`)
2. Using a `&str` as opposed to a `String`.
3. Printing a non-`Display` type with `{}`.
4. Trying to move out of borrowed values.

All the issues fixed, the code looks like:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;

use rustc_serialize::json::{Json, ToJson};

#[derive(Debug)]
enum ApiResult<T: Sized + ToJson> {
    Ok(T),
    Err(T),
}

trait ToApiResult<T: Sized + ToJson> {
    fn to_api_result(&self) -> ApiResult<T>;
}

impl ToApiResult<Json> for Result<Option<String>, String> {
    fn to_api_result(&self) -> ApiResult<Json> {
        match *self {
            Ok(Some(ref text)) => ApiResult::Ok(text.to_json()),
            Ok(None) => ApiResult::Err(().to_json()),
            Err(ref e) => ApiResult::Err(e.to_json()),
        }
    }
}

fn main(){
    let r = Result::Ok(Some("hello".to_string()));
    print!("{:?}", r.to_api_result());
}
```

Comment: Oh, I can't believe it was something so trivial. Thanks for pointing it out + fixing the other bugs. The compiler hadn't gotten to the end so I didn't pay attention to them!